# MySQL: Loop over all entries to update parent table

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a parent table "user" and a child table "profile". For every profile there also exists a user with the same id, but not the other way round. profiles have names, and now I added the property name also to users.

I would like to fire an MySQL-Statements that loops over all profiles, grabs the user with the same id, and updates the column name of the user, with the name of the profile.

How can I do that? I never used loops in an SQL-Statement before..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@KenDowns was right, you dont need forloops. But his statement had a small flaw. Here is the correct one, that worked for me (you dont need a from-clause):

```
UPDATE user, profile
SET user.name = profile.name
WHERE profile.id = user.id
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL is set-based and does not require loops for things like this:

```
UPDATE profiles
   set name = user.name
  from user
 where profiles.userId = user.userId
```

Comment: I adapted your statement (I want to update the users, not the profiles), but I get an 1064. Here is my complete statement:
UPDATE rpl_user
   set name = rpl_profile.name
  from rpl_profile
 where rpl_profile.id = rpl_user.id
 What am I missing?